# Image Cells return as blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell with the formula

```
=image("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", 4, 50, 100)
```

In my google script when I select the cell it says the cell is blank. Ideally I want to get the formula

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
Logger.log(range.isBlank())   #returns true
```

As I am looping through the range's formulas I would like to be able to do as follows

```
var formulas = range.getFormulas(); 
for (var i = 0; i < formulas[0].length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < formulas.length; j++){
     Logger.log(formulas[j][i]);
```

This code works with all other formulas I've tried

Comment: Yes, `range.isBlank() //returns true`, but `range.getFormulas()`still get the formula as `=image()` in the array. I am basically unclear on what you are trying to do, or ask here!

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize Isblank only looks for values, not formulas. I was filtering out any blank cells so I didn't run my code when it didn't have to be run. Thanks.